# Can you use jQuery's $(this) in a one-line code to modify elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, html

I'm working on a placeholder function in jquery. Right now, I just want the form element to change its value to whatever its placeholder is. I tried the following code:

```
$('input:text').val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
```

But it doesn't work. After testing it a little, I realized the problem is with using `$(this)` in that context. How can I change this so that it will loop through all form elements and change their value to their placeholder attribute?

Comment: `this` can only differ within functions, not in an argument without a function. Here, `this` is the same as `this` used outside this line of code in the same function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input:text').val(function() {
    return $(this).attr('placeholder');
});
```

or:

```
$('input:text').attr('value', function() {
    return $(this).attr('placeholder');
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ch4pA/).

Answer (score 5):

Most of these setter jQuery functions provide a way to specify a function whose return value will be used. This is a way to make use of `$(this)`.

```
$('input:text').val(function () {
  return $(this).attr('placeholder');
});
```

[jQuery val() Reference](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)